# Neovim remap for vscode for commenting doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, neovim

This is my current code

```
map z, <Cmd>call VSCodeNotifyRange('editor.action.commentLine', getline('.'), getline('.') + v:count1, 1)<CR>
```

Usage of VSCodeNotifyRange used as explained in the Neovim extension's [readme](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim#invoking-vscode-actions-from-neovim):

What I'm trying to do: I pass a number to the remap, for example 5z,

The current line and four next lines are selected in vscode, and then commented out

What's happening: nothing gets commented out, and I get jumped to the line I specified the number to

So when I use 5z, I end up on line 5 (absolute). When I use 10z, I end up on line 10, and so on

I imagine this is a syntax issue, any help would be appreciated